# AirDrop not working on ALL Wi-Fi networks

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, wifi, airdrop

I have recently discovered that AirDrop works with the Wi-Fi Networks on my school and office. But not on my Home Wi-Fi network.

I previously thought that AirDrop between my MacBook Air and iPhone 5S does not work. But it seems that the problem is in my Home Wi-Fi network. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The basic things to do are turning On and Off Airdrop, upgrading your Mac to its latest OS, reset the Network Settings on your iPhone, and adjust the FireWall settings on your Mac. Doing one or more of those should help you fix the problem.

Source: http://appletoolbox.com/2016/02/airdrop-not-working-7-tips/

Comment: Did all the steps mentioned and still doesn't work.

I think the problem may be on my home network, not on my devices.

Comment: AirDrop is flaky, regardless of the network you're on.  I can get it to work 2/3's of the time on all different kinds of networks and I can't figure out why it works on some and not others.